# Creating an Empty Universal Application with Xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-app

In previous versions of Xcode creating a window-based, universal application would populate the project with iPhone and iPad specific files and assign the appropriate entry points.  All that was required was modifications to the iPhone/iPad controllers/xibs to create device specific interfaces.

Sadly, XCode 4.3 no longer offers a window-based template (empty application is the closest) and I don't know how to appropriately configure the entry points.  This is fairly strait forward using [storyboarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890111/how-to-create-a-universal-application-using-xcode-4-2-empty-application-template/9979238#9979238), but I would like to do it using programmatic or xib-based work flows.

I have created two view controllers and xibs: `HomeViewController_iPhone` and `HomeViewController_iPad`. Simply setting the entry point for each device to the appropriate HomeViewController crashes the app. I suspect I need to do a bit more to subclass the application delegate, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something like what I do when using a navigation controller aswell. Depending on the device the code loads the correct xib. This goes in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the `AppDelegate.m`.  `navigationController` is a property in `AppDelegate.h`

```
UIViewController *rootViewController;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    rootViewController = [[HomeViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
}
else {
    rootViewController = [[HomeViewController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                 initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] 
               initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Hope it helps towards a solution!